# How to omit/suppress one element from SELECT before sending the form

Tags: javascript, select, element

before transmitting a SELECT object/array to the PHP processing, I'd like to suppress/omit a potentially empty element. As my SELECT box offers something like a NULL option:

```
 <select name="a">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
```

I'd like to suppress the NULL value if it has been selected, like this:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="document.formIndex.a.OMIT-ELEMENT(''); document.formIndex.submit(); return false">search</a>
```

Haven't found anything really useful. Thanks for any hints how this could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function resetNullValue (element)
{
   if (element.value == null )
   {
      element.value = "";
   }
}
```

But why do you want to suppress it on the HTML side? You should handle it on the server side always

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ok, I will rethink my approach then.